# Replace link to wiki article with article content

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to reproduce small wiki engine from this [tutorial](http://showmedo.com/videotutorials/video?name=1100000&fromSeriesID=110). 
In this tutorial they use custom filter to wikify page:

```
from django import template
import re
wikilink = re.compile("\\b([A-Z][a-z]+[A-Z][a-z]+)\\b")
register = template.Library()
@register.filter
def wikify(value):
    return wikilink.sub(r"<a href='/wikicamp/\1/'>\1</a>", value)
```

Wiki articles are deafined by models.
I want to replace wikiwords in article not with a link, but with first ten words from target article. How to do it with django filters or is there a better way to do it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a function to `re.sub`. The model used for wiki articles is not clear but here is an example:

```
def repl(m):
   return WikiArticles.objects.get(title=m.group(1)).content[:10]

@register.filter
def wikify(value):
    return wikilink.sub(repl, value)
```

Note: The first ten characters are returned not words.